# Package Source Path not populated while using DtExecUI.exe

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, bids, dtexec

I had SQL Server 2008 installed earlier. I had the ability to right click on any SSIS package and select Open With   **"SQL Server 2008 Integration Services Package Execution Utility"** as an option to run the package standalone.

Recently, we upgraded to **SQL Server 2014** and now I don't see this option when I right click. I browsed manually and located DtExecUI.exe to open with however Package Source is not being populated automatically (Screenshot attached).

Is there any work around for this ?

[image]

Comment: What values are available in the Package Source dropdown?

Comment: What does the menu look like when you right-click a .dtsx file now? When you choose "Open with...", what are the options available?

Comment: Drop down gives me options as expected so I can select File system and provide path however I don't want to do this manually. Ideally, DtExexUI should get path when I right click and open (that's what happening until now with 2008 version).

Comment: when I right click I could see only "Visual Studio Version Selector (2013)". Later on I browsed manually and set "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\DtExecUI.exe" as open with option but facing this issue.

Comment: SSIS is notoriously finicky about package target versions. Have you tried upgrading your sql2008 packages to sql2014? That would be the first thing I try. I'm unable to reproduce your issue, but I don't have any packages made in sql2008.

Comment: @digital.aaron thanks for checking on this. It seems this issue is realted to install/windows  as DtexecUI should get path when we reference through right click. I already upgraded packages to 2014 and everything works fine. There are no issues related to SSIS Functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires a registry hack. We are on 2017 and experienced the same issue.  The Package source and Package does not get filled in. I fixed it by tweaking the DTExecUI command registry key by adding a `/F` for file.

At a command prompt, go to this registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\DTExecUI.exe\shell\open\command
```

Put a `/F` between the command and the `"%1"`.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\DTExecUI.exe" /F "%1"
```

Now it is filled in when you right click on a .dtsx and select "Execute Package Utility".

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the slick solution I was looking for. Also, do you know if there is anyway I can make 2008 DTEXEC as default. looks like some drivers didnt work with this version (for Example - Oracle Attunity)